# For binary search for keys in an array, what is the final value of lo or hi?

Tags: java, arrays, search, rank

Assume integer keys with sorted keys array: `int[] keys = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70};` So initially in rank `lo = 0` and `hi = 6`.

For binary search for 30 in the keys array, would the final value of lo be 20, which is 1?

I just need to make sense of the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary search would start like so:

```
lo = 0, hi = 6, mid = 3, numberInMid = 40
```

As `30 < 40`, `hi = mid - 1 = 2`
Now,
`lo = 0, hi = 2, mid = 1, numberInMid = 20`

As `30 > 20`, `lo = mid + 1 = 2`
Finally,
`lo = 2, hi = 2, mid = 2, numberInMid = 30`

As `30 == 30`, loop exits and `ans = 30`
If instead, you were searching for say 35 (I take this number since it fits with all above relational expressions), then:
As `35 > 30`, `lo = mid + 1 = 3`,
Since, `lo > hi`, loop exits and you are returned the default value of `ans`. 
Eg:`ans = -1` if only positive integers are involved or instead, you may even use a `flag = false` which only switches to true when an `==` expression is hit.

Comment: what happens if its searching something that is not on the list? like example 5? would high be 0 and low would be -1?

Comment: Please see my updated explanation above. In the case of 5, you would come across `lo = -1` which is also not possible and hence the loop will be broken. Mind you, the while loop checks for `lo >= 0 && hi < N && lo <= hi`.

Comment: so in the case of looking for 35, the lo would be 3, which is 40? wouldnt the low be 30 which is 2?

Comment: Initially, yes. But see my example. When the checker finds that `35 > 30`, it would increment `lo` so that now, `lo = 3`. It is at that point that `lo <= hi` will return false and thus it will exit the loop

Comment: So if it was right where we left of and searched again, then its low would be 3? Thank makes sense, but I was asking for the searches to restart every search using the initial sorted keys array :) thank you , i will practice this some more

Comment: Your very welcome. If you liked my answer, please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the code and trace it by **debug** for understanding.

```
public class Test {
    public int binary_search(int[] keys, int low, int high, int mid, int target){
        if(low > high){
            return -1;
        }

        if(target < keys[mid]){
            high = mid - 1;
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            return binary_search(keys, low, high, mid, target);
        }else if(target > keys[mid]){
            low = mid + 1;
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            return binary_search(keys, low, high, mid, target);
        }else{
            return mid;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] keys = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
        Test test = new Test();
        int mid = (0 + keys.length) / 2;
        int target = 30;
        int index = test.binary_search(keys, 0, keys.length, mid, target); 
        System.out.println(index);
    }
}
```